# I am not able to install eclipse after uninstalling it

Tags: apt, eclipse

To remove Eclipse I used:

`sudo apt-get autoremove eclipse`
`rm -r ~/.eclipse/`

Now when installing i get this:

```
anjali@anjali-ThinkPad-Edge-E430:~$ sudo apt-get install eclipse
[sudo] password for anjali: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
eclipse is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 608 not upgraded.
anjali@anjali-ThinkPad-Edge-E430:~$ eclipse
The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

Comment: What happens when you do `sudo apt-get purge eclipse && sudo apt-get install eclipse` ?

Comment: Post this command output: `dpkg -l | grep eclipse`

Comment: Why not upgrading the system along te way... you have 608 packages no upgraded.

Answer (score 3):

```
The program 'eclipse' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install eclipse-platform
```

And one more thing, to uninstall a package use:

```
sudo apt-get remove package_name
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

See `man apt-get` for more info:

> ```
> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically
> installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no
> longer needed.
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Is not more easy install directly from Eclipse sources? you dont need install everything more,just download the zip and unzip it and Eclipse works fine, I do that all the time with no problems. Only Java is a requirement but I guess you already got it.

Comment: Actually the less you manually touch your system and use apt instead the better. Installing eclipse from the repos reassures you that it will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: Doing that you obtain an old version, and if you dont know "install" Eclipse is only download the zip, unzip and run it, so no files are installed or compiled.